# Firebase auth session lost in IE9 on reload with Firebase v1.1.0 to 2.0.3

Tags: session, internet-explorer-9, firebase

The Firebase authentication session is lost in Internet Explorer 9 with Firebase version 1.1.0 to 2.0.3 when you reload the page.

Example below and live at: http://codepen.io/hoenderdaal/pen/Lymzn 
(Rename  to your own Firebase database)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.3/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="login()">Login with Password</button><button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
<hr>
<b>AuthInfo:</b><span id="authInfo"></span>
<script>
    var fbRef = new Firebase("https://<firebase_database>.firebaseio.com/");

    fbRef.onAuth(function(authData){
        if (authData) {
            document.getElementById('authInfo').innerHTML = 'User ' + authData.uid + ' authenticated via the ' + authData.provider + ' provider!';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('authInfo').innerHTML =  'User is logged out.';
        }
    });

    var login = function(){
        fbRef.authWithPassword({
            email: 'ie9test@domain.tld',
            password: '123'}
        , function(error, authData){

        });
    }
    var logout = function(){
        fbRef.unauth();
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Richard, it's unclear what you mean here by reload. Are you saying that after upgrading to 2.x, that the session is lost on any reload? Or that specifically, when switching from 1.x to 2.x, that the session is not shared across versions? The latter is expected behavior, the former would not be.

Comment: @Richard It looks like there is a bug here in the Firebase web client. I'll take a look and see if we can't get it sorted out for you. In general, if you think you've found a bug, reach out to support@firebase.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the Firebase Web client version 1.1.0 to 2.0.3 and is solved in version 2.0.4.

Form the changelog at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html

> Fixed bug impacting auth session persistence in IE9 and below.